# ffmpeg distributed transcoding

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transcoding

I have a 100GB 1080p video file which I want to transcode to 720 h264. Since transcoding is computationally expensive, i wanted to transcode smaller portions of video & stitch it back together. Can we use ffmpeg seek to transcode 10seconds of video & stitch it back together? When I am reading through blogs they mention to go with GOP. I want to get opinion with below approach. Any help is appreciated.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i 80Gb.mp4 -t 10  -s 720x720 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac chunk1.mp4 
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -i 80Gb.mp4 -t 10 -s 720x720 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac chunk2.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:20 -i 80Gb.mp4 -t 10 -s 720x720 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac chunk2.mp4
```

...

Comment: Use the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment) instead of multiple commands.

Answer (score 0):

The mention of GOP is likely for slicing a video **without transcoding**. 
You slice at keyframes (since each one is the start of a new *Group Of Pictures*).

Since you are doing a full re-encoding to a different picture size, there is nothing wrong with your setup. You can rejoin them afterwards either with muxing or with `concat` into one container file.

Comment: thanks for responding. is there any best practise on how to choose the part duration? So we have less overlapping time between parts